# openvpn with ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-server

> ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: could not execute external program

When command: `sudo openvpn server.conf`

Would anyone have a solution to this problem?

My server.conf folder:

## serveur TCP/443

```
mode server

proto tcp

port 443

dev tun

# Cles et certificats

ca ca.crt

cert server.crt

key server.key

dh dh1024.pem

tls-auth ta.key 1

key-direction 0

cipher AES-256-CBC

# Reseau

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

; push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.131.21"

; push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

keepalive 10 120

# Securite

user nobody

group nogroup

chroot /etc/openvpn/jail

persist-key

persist-tun

comp-lzo

# Log
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does not work: you are jailing into a directory where I bet there is no such thing as iproute2 suite, to change the routing table. Also, I am not sure your restrictions on user and group will allow you to change routing table.

try, as a simple experiment, to run the sever without the three statements:

```
 user nobody
 group nogroup
 chroot /etc/openvpn/jail
```

And see whether it works (my money is on **it does**). Then check whether the introducton of these two statements *alone* allows you to run openvpn correctly:

```
 user nobody
 group nogroup
```

(BTW, do you have this user and group? Not all distros do, and not necessarily automatically).

Lastly, you may try to enforce the chroot, but you will have to provide a *working* chroot, *i.e.* one with enough programs installed to make it work. I bet your current chroot does not even have a shell, from the look of it.

Comment: thanks i'v now a problem of security without my jail folder...

Comment: No you don't. The certificate structure is pretty safe as it is. Many apps (Sonos, do you have it, for instance?) connect to their home base like this without any problem. You may relax.

Comment: ok thanks for your help, and sorry for my inexperience